# oracle apex Breadcrumbs set item value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have breadcrumb on page **n°3** described as below:

```
Home >> Page 1 >> Page 2 >> Page 3
```

I have **P03_ID_CLIENT** item in **Page 3** and **P02_ID_CLIENT** in the **Page 2**

My question is: When I click on **Page 2** in the Breadcrumb, How can I affect the value of **P03_ID_CLIENT** item to **P02_ID_CLIENT** in the Page 2

I tried with Branches but it seems that I had to trigger an action to set the value of the item in the target page

Answer (score 0):

I think the mention of breadcrumbs is superfluous. Are you requiring a *Computation* on *Before Regions* to set P03_ID_CLIENT to the value stored in P0_ID_CLIENT?